# How to compress variables in Java using leading zero byte suppression?

Tags: java, jvm, compression

Leading zero byte suppression means that leading zero bytes of an integer value will be removed and instead the number of eliminated bytes is stored. For example: suppose we have 32-bit integers, hexadecimal value `00000090` will be encoded as binary value `01110010000`, where 011 means there are 3 zero bytes in `00000090`.

My question is how to implement leading zero byte suppression in Java? Could anyone give me some examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, you suggest that `0x00000090` be encoded as the 11-bit number `0b01110010000`. As you probably know, there are no 11-bit data types in Java, so doing this "the Java way" would be impossible.

The only way I can think of to achieve what you're trying to do would be to use a single byte array to store all of your data, then implement zero byte suppression algorithms on top of that. Of course, that would remove the entire point of Java, which is to be object-oriented.

If you're trying to implement some sort of `IntegerZeroByteSuppression` class, your effort will be for naught, because every object in Java comes with several bytes of overhead anyway, far outweighing the few bits you'll save from the zero byte suppression itself.

In the end, if you *really* need the few bits of memory you'll save from this (doubtful, but I don't actually know what you're working on), I would suggest either finding a language with little to no overhead in its object-oriented capabilities (e.g. C++) or a language that implements zero byte suppression by default (?).

Comment: I am currently reading this paper: [link](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~rgemulla/publications/schlegel11fp.pdf). In this paper, it used "leading zero byte suppression" to compress all nodes of a CFP-Tree. As is said in this paper, it implemented this algorithm in C++. I just wonder is there any possibility to implement it in Java. So it seems that Java is not suitable for my goal.

Comment: @Mark you can implement the same algorithms in Java as C++.  I suspect you have mis-understood the problem.  I use stop bit encoding which provides much the same benefits.  It uses 1 byte for every 7 bits used which allows a 64-bit number to be stored in one byte.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The problem isn't whether you can or cannot implement the algorithm; the problem is that in this case, the algorithm would be used only for memory optimization purposes, and as I'm sure you know, optimization varies between languages, compilers, and devices. A Java implementation is possible here, but not practical.

Comment: @RedRoboHood I use stop bit encoding in Java.  I don't see why it would be any more or less practical in Java.  The are many more complex compression algorithms in Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I think there may be a lapse in communication here. Are we talking about compressing variables in memory while the program runs, or compressing arbitrary data that the program is acting on (e.g. reading a file of binary integers, compressing it, then writing it to another file)?

Comment: @RedRoboHood I use compression for both in Java.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Could you give me a link to an example of the former?

Comment: @RedRoboHood there is no simple example.  I have an off heap map storing either in direct memory or memory mapped files. I use simple data compression for writing the data off heap e.g. stop bit encoding, as well as the option to use Snappy, LZ4 or LZW compression of this data. In Java this looks like a plan Map, of values which are interfaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81652/discussion-between-redrobohood-and-peter-lawrey).

Comment: @PeterLawrey I don't know what the "library" you refer to? From your discussion, it seems that I can add a "library" which helps me to finish the compression task. Could you give me a link of such "library", please?

Comment: @Mark There are libraries which do something very similar to what you want which shows it is possible, I don't know of any library which does exactly what you want.